# Show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{q}x^{n}$ is absolutely convergent, and that $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^qx^n=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let x be a real number with $|x|<1$, and *q* be a real number. Show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{q}x^{n}$ is absolutely convergent, and that $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^qx^n=0$.

My attempt:

Let $c = n^q$

Then since, $$\sum_{i=m}^{n} (ca_i) = c(\sum_{i=m}^{n} a_i),$$ we can write

$$c\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{n}$$
and by a Lemma concerning geometric series, if $|x|<1$ then $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{n}$$ is  absolutely convergent. If it is absolutely convergent it is also conditionally convergent. Now I can use the zero test and we see that the limit of $x^n$ as n->infinity = 0.

Comment: $n$ is a variable in your sum. You can't define $c = n^q$ and factor it out of the sum. Try the ratio test.

Comment: In some places you have written $a^q$ and in others $n^q$. Which do you mean?

Comment: @Bungo i meant $n^q$ thanks i fixed it

Comment: Note entirely a duplicate, since this question is about a particular attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Our series has $n$-th term $a_n=n^qx^n$ and thus$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=x\cdot \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^q=x\cdot \left( 1+\frac1n \right)^q$$

It follows that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left \lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right \rvert=\lvert x \rvert <1$, so by the ratio test the series $\sum\limits_{n\geq 1} a_n$ converges absolutely.

EDIT: Granted, if $\sum\limits_{n\geq 1} \lvert a_n \rvert$ converges, then $\lvert a_n\rvert \to 0$, so $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n^qx^n=0$ whenever $\lvert x \rvert <1$.

Comment: Yeah thats not how you apply the ratio test

Comment: @daniels_pa Could you be more clear? The ratio test clearly applies.

Comment: It does apply but the $x$ doesn't show up at the end in the ratio test. $a_{n+1},a_n$ are functions of $n$ not $x$

Comment: You're thinking in terms of power series. For each fixed $x$ with $\lvert x \rvert < 1$, the ratio test applies and the series converges. You *can* use power series tech here to deduce more than just (absolute) convergence, but for the question at hand it suffices.

Comment: Yy correct, i thought you were looking at power series. And even after i thought that you need to prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n^qx^n=0$ but this suffices

Answer (score -1):

By ration test we examine

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{n^q}{(n+1)^q}=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^q=1
$$

Here we actually applied [Cauchy-Haramard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem) theorem

So we know that this power series absolutely converges on (-1,1) (on -1,1 the series obviously diverges)